# Unknown exceptions when connecting to MongoDB via java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm currently trying to connect to a mongoDB database via the java driver and I'm given the exceptions listed below when I run the code above it. Not sure what to do or what's wrong. If it appears to be an import or JRE problem please list the part to import if you can.

Code in Java:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new 
MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://wendulem:MYPASSWORD@cluster0 
ugj9q.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"));
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("GradeU");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
    database.getCollection("profiles");
    Document myDoc;
    myDoc = collection.find(eq("username", "admin")).first();
    System.out.println(myDoc.toJson());
```

Console Logs:

```
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='Cluster0-shard-0'}
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Adding discovered server cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@11438d26 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:4355}] to cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:4703}] to cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:7669}] to cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=21097463, setName='Cluster0-shard-0', canonicalAddress=cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000001, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Fri Jul 06 12:49:50 EDT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=75088686541038}
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=28398802, setName='Cluster0-shard-0', canonicalAddress=cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Fri Jul 06 12:49:50 EDT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=75088689801046}
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 5]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=22170448, setName='Cluster0-shard-0', canonicalAddress=cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-01-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017, cluster0-shard-00-02-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Fri Jul 06 12:49:50 EDT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=75088684046959}
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Setting max election id to 7fffffff0000000000000001 from replica set primary cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Setting max set version to 1 from replica set primary cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Discovered replica set primary cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017
Jul 06, 2018 12:49:56 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4}] to cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='wendulem', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:173)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$300(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:151)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:64)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:390)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:455)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:401)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:695)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:198)
    at gradebook.grademain.main(grademain.java:39)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8000 (AtlasError): 'bad auth Authentication failed.' on server cluster0-shard-00-00-ugj9q.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "bad auth Authentication failed.", "code" : 8000, "codeName" : "AtlasError" }
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:293)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:67)
```

Comment: Can you add the code that configures the connection to MongoDB?  The error message looks like the authentication is incorrect: 

     "errmsg" : "bad auth Authentication failed."

Comment: The best way to get good formatting is just to edit your original post and add it there :)

Comment: Added it toward the top

Comment: Are you able to connect via mongo shell with  `mongo cluster0-ugj9q.mongodb.net/test -u wendulem -p MYPASSWORD`?

Comment: it's saying missing ; before the statement? Tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: use quotes around your password. You should have some special characters in it to escape?

Comment: putting double quotes and single quotes around the password in the shell and eclipse does nothing

Comment: nevermind I changed the special character in my password and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your passwords don't end in $ because that's what my problem was, it is not necessary to quote in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If credentials are correct and MongoDB Atlas Cloud details are correct, Then It is problem of mismatch version of mongoDB driver and connection string.

First try with latest

**mongodb+srv://**

Or else try with below connection string if still a problem

**"mongodb://**

2nd driver string is working for me.

Answer (score -2):

Increasing socketTimeoutMS and adding authSource param fixed this issue.

```html
Ex: mongodb://<user>:<pwd>@<mongoServer>:<port>/<db_name>?socketTimeoutMS=1000000&authSource=<db_name>
```